# Hide files in Gnome permamently

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 15.04

Whenever I hide files (Ctrl-H), when I start up Nautilus again the previously hidden files will show up again. I'm using Gnome. I don't seem to have a menu -> preferences like other postings state.

**Solution:** In Gnome: Click on the title for Nautilus in the task bar and then on settings. Inside is a setting to hide files permanently.

[image]

Comment: What file are you trying to hide and what are you doing to hide them?

Comment: Ctrl-H, I guess this are system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine, but you need to permanently change the view.

Go to `Edit > Preferences > Views` and turn off `Show hidden and backup files`.

That should do it.

Comment: Only until I close Nautilus. Is it a bug?

Comment: @empedokles New edit

Comment: Nautilus has no written menu structure in Gnome.

Comment: @empedokles right-click the tab of the program, where in other environments you can select minimise, close, etc. - from there select Preferences

Comment: Thanks. It's not quite there, but I found it now and will upload a screenshot above.

Comment: @empedokles - now select Preferences (guessing 'Einstellungen' in German), and in the [Views tabs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/28SlT.png) you should have the option for it - make sure it is off. To turn it on/off temporarily press 'Ctrl'+'H' or enable/disable hidden stuff in the View menu (downward triangle button).

Comment: Yes I have found it. Thx.

Comment: Yeah, well it wasn't really precise for Gnome.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to hide files on Linux/Unix is to add a leading dot into the filename. Typically it's done in command line but you can do it through nautilus as well

1. Click on the file
2. Click <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Add a leading dot in the filename. For example , rename `myStory.txt` to `.myStory.txt`
4. Refresh with <kbd>F5</kbd> key; your file will be hiddne now.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I think OP means already existing dot files are showing up when nautilus starts rather than how to create a hidden file. If nautilus menu no longer has a setting for this, he needs to use dconf-editor.

Comment: My problem is that .files are being shown. There is a setting to hide, but if I close Nautilus and restart the files are shown again.

Comment: @empedokles OK, that clarifies things. Can you please run this `gsettings list-recursively | grep 'nautilus' | grep 'hidden' ` in terminal and let me know what it says. Also, are you on Ubuntu 15.04 ?

Comment: Ok, you have 15.04 tag, I see.

Comment: @Serg : `nuc@nuc:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep 'nautilus' | grep 'hidden'
org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files false
org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files false`